# Treat no extension files as html?

Tags: html, .htaccess, file, text

So I'm recreating a website from web.archive.org. I've downloaded it and it has many pages. The problem is that the past site was a forum php script and now I obviously can't recreate it again. Nevertheless I will be satisfied with only being an html until I build something else.

So the problem now is that there are a lot of files generated from the query urls like this:

```
index.php@lang=fr
index.php@lang=fr&section=4
index.php@lang=fr&section=5
index.php@section=15&fonc=imp&lang=fr
```

etc...

And when I upload these files to my server the browser threats these no-extension files as text instead of an html, despite the html content inside.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and is there an easy way to solve it?

EDIT: So apparently is the download software that I used which replaced the original urls ? with @. But if I just bulk rename all files from @ to ? they still won't open. So how about the ultimate solution below, how to do that painless and fast?

Ultimately I would like to place each of the old files in one folder and rename them to html and then create htaccess rules from the original URLs to each file respectively in that folder. However doing this manually would take infinite time. So can anyone suggest a simpler solution to this?

Comment: @JohnConde You're not following what he's done here.  These are the names of files (named after the original path and query string for archival), and the `?` has been replaced with `@` since `?` cannot be used in a file name on many filesystems.

Comment: Hey you're right, OMG how could've been so blind! It's the download manager that somehow replaced those ? with @ while retriving the files from web archive. Thanks a lot man, I will just bulk rename the files now.

Comment: You won't be able to as you likely won't be able to use `?` in your file name, and you shouldn't anyway.  Whatever downloaded these files likely rewrote the links.  Also if you do this you will have to escape the `?` in the URL anyway.  Don't bother renaming.

Comment: But I just tried replacing the @ with ? and it seems like they open fine in the browser. This would suffice for now, but I would still want to solve this like the Ultimate Way I described in my edited question. Do you know how to do that easy and fast?

Comment: Actually you're right, ? just messes things up..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your default content type is likely configured to be `text/plain` (which is the default in Apache).  With HTTP, a resource type is not indicated by a file name extension, it is indicated by the `Content-Type` response header.

I think that you will have to set the default `Content-Type` header with this directive in your configuration:

```
DefaultType text/html
```

See also:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#defaulttype

Comment: This works very well and it is a fast solution as I needed. Thanks a lot Brad!